# Dapper OracleMappingType.RefCursor direction: ParameterDirection.Input not working

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, .net-core, dapper

in my C# I have a list of objects with values to be inserted into a table in my Oracle db, I'm using a foreach to scroll through the list and send record by record to a function in a pck and there I make an insert. I'm using dapper to do this. But the problem is that it takes too long when there are too many records. Ex 35000 inserts.
I wonder if I can send the entire list to the bank and there I can do all the inserts at once. I thought about the possibility of using an `OracleMappingType.RefCursor direction: ParameterDirection.Input` but the RefCursor doesn't work for the input type only for output. Would anyone know how to tell me a way to pass the entire list to the db and there I can make the inserts?

The method below is the form I am using today but it takes a long time when I have a very large list of data.

```c#
string query = "PCK_TEST.FC_IMPORT_VALUES";

            foreach (var item in ListOfValues)
            {
                var param = new OracleDynamicParameters();

                param.Add("P_VALUE_A", dbType: OracleMappingType.Varchar2, direction: ParameterDirection.Input, value: item.ValueA);
                param.Add("P_VALUE_B", dbType: OracleMappingType.Date, direction: ParameterDirection.Input, value: item.ValueB);
                param.Add("P_VALUE_C", dbType: OracleMappingType.Decimal, direction: ParameterDirection.Input, value: item.ValueC);
                param.Add("P_VALUE_D", dbType: OracleMappingType.Decimal, direction: ParameterDirection.Input, value: item.ValueD);
                param.Add("P_VALUE_E", dbType: OracleMappingType.Decimal, direction: ParameterDirection.Input, value: item.ValueE);
                param.Add("P_VALUE_F", dbType: OracleMappingType.Decimal, direction: ParameterDirection.Input, value: item.ValueF);
                param.Add("P_VALUE_G", dbType: OracleMappingType.Decimal, direction: ParameterDirection.Input, value: item.ValueG);
                param.Add("P_VALUE_H", dbType: OracleMappingType.Decimal, direction: ParameterDirection.Input, value: item.ValueH);
                param.Add("P_VALUE_I", dbType: OracleMappingType.Decimal, direction: ParameterDirection.Input, value: item.ValueI);
                param.Add("P_VALUE_J", dbType: OracleMappingType.Varchar2, direction: ParameterDirection.Input, value: item.ValueJ);
                param.Add("P_VALUE_K", dbType: OracleMappingType.Decimal, direction: ParameterDirection.Input, value: item.ValueK);
                param.Add("P_VALUE_L", dbType: OracleMappingType.Varchar2, direction: ParameterDirection.Input, value: item.ValueL);
                param.Add("P_RETORN", dbType: OracleMappingType.Varchar2, size: 4000, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

                await SqlMapper.ExecuteAsync(_con, query, param: param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                var erro = param.Get<string>("P_RETORN");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me: [Oracle bulk data insert](http://www.mukeshkumar.net/articles/csharp/two-ways-to-insert-bulk-data-into-oracle-database-using-csharp)